# Changing the background of the image on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, web

I have an image for which I need to change the background onclick. I used following javascript and html to do the thing. For simplicity I first preferred red background and for the reference image is with transparent background.

Code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe id="myframe" src="img-thing.png"></iframe>

<p>Click the button to change the background color of the picture contained in the iframe.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var x = document.getElementById("myframe");
var y = (x.contentWindow || x.contentDocument);

y.body.style.backgroundColor="red";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I know there might be something wrong to use iframe here so i tried :

```
<div id="myframe"><img src="img-thing.png"></div>
```

instead of the iframe. If I remove the src field from the iframe tag it works fine. But when I insert image and click try now it does not work. Please help.

Comment: Please ignore my bad English.

Comment: The `iframe` tag does not have the attribute `img src`. It has the attribute `src` but not `img src`

Comment: Sorry I tried that but still no result.

Comment: I don't understand this line: `if (y.document)y = y.document;` What is `y.document`?

Comment: Even I am not sure. I picked up that part from http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_iframe_contentdocument

Comment: I removed that line and still no change. Which means you are right@chris97ong that line is not of any use.

Comment: I think that line is for browser support...

Comment: Okay Sir! I tried div in place of iframe. Anything wrong with that?

Comment: It should work. You can then change the background color by:

`document.getElementById("someimg").style.backgroundColor = "red";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you use an iframe ?
Use an **img** tag in a **div** and update the background color of the div

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="myframe"><img src="http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110821045825/meme/images/3/3d/LOLGuy.png" />    </div>

<p>Click the button to change the background color of the picture contained in the iframe.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction(){
    var myframe = document.getElementById('myframe');
    myframe.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TZXU3/1/

Comment: Great it worked!  Thanks @Anthony. Just a minor issue ,I used iframe because I wanted the image to be enclosed in the frame.

Answer (score 1):

```
<iframe id="myframe" src="img-thing.png"></iframe>
```

A `png` file is an image file. It has no `body` tag. So it will not work. Instead, try putting a HTML link (eg. `something.html`) in the `src` attribute. Hope that helps.

If you want to change the background color of an image, use the `img` tag, not `iframe`. Then you can directly access the `img` element and change its background color, like `document.getElementById("someimg").style.backgroundColor = "red";`

Comment: Thanks @chris97ong. Quite valuable info.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change different color on clicking the button, then try this, it may help you

```
function changePic(picColor) {
   if(picName == "btnRed")
     {
        document.getElementById(mainPic).src = "mainPicRed.jpg"
      } 
   else if(picName == "btnbtnYellow ")
     {
       document.getElementById(mainPic).src = "mainPicYellow.jpg"
    } 
}
```